# Errors after upgrading Azure function to .NET 7 for a Service Bus trigger function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

After upgrading Azure Functions to .NET 7, I resolved build errors by installing some NuGet packages and refactoring code. However, when I run my function then I get this error:

```
Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'xyz': Cannot convert input parameter 'messageReceiver' to type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver' from type 'System.String'. Error:System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver'.
System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver'.
```

This is the code I have is:

```
public async Task SendOrderFunctionTrigger([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        //Validate Message
        var (group,checkOrder) = ValidateMessage(message);

        //Retrieve Message Payload
        var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
        
    switch (CheckOrder)
        {   
    var orderPlaced = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderPlaced>(json);
    //Rest of the code logic
    }
        
        //Mark Message as Complete in Service Bus
        await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
   }
}

private static (Group group, CheckOrder checkOrder)ValidateMessage(Message message)
{               
    //rest of the code logic is in the solution section
}
```

Solution I tried:

After upgrading to .NET 7, I got errors on the `Message` attribute and changed it to `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` and `ServiceBusReceiver` in the method signature. Also changed the JSON value from `Encoding.UTF8` to `message.body.ToStream`.

```
public async Task SendOrderFunctionTrigger([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusReceiver messageReceiver)
{
  try
    {
    //Validate Message
    var (group,CheckOrder) = ValidateMessage(message);

    //Retrieve Message Payload
    //var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    var json = message.Body.ToStream().ToString();

    // Deserialize the JSON payload into the appropriate type
    var orderPlaced = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OrderPlaced>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));

    switch (CheckOrder)
        {   
    //Rest of the code logic
    }
    //Mark Message as Complete in Service Bus
    await messageReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
       }
}

private static (Group group, CheckOrder checkOrder)ValidateMessage(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
{               
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Label)) // this line was throwing an error at message.label as that is not acceptable in .Net 7
        //    throw new Exception($"some error");

        // Below lines is to resolve the "message.Label" error
        if (!message.ApplicationProperties.TryGetValue("Label", out var labelObj) || !(labelObj is string label) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(label))
            throw new Exception($"some error");

        //var hasChannel = message.UserProperties.TryGetValue("Channel", out var channelValue); // this line was erroring at message.UserProperties
        //Below line is to resolve message.UserProperties error
        var hasChannel = message.ApplicationProperties.TryGetValue("Channel", out var channelValue);
        if (!hasChannel || string.IsNullOrEmpty(channelValue?.ToString()))
            throw new Exception($"some error");

    var isValidGroup = Enum.TryParse<Group>(groupValue.ToString(), out var group);

        //var isValidOrder = Enum.TryParse<CheckOrder>(message.Label, out var checkOrder); // this line was erroring at message.label

        //Below lines of code is to resolve message.label error
        string label1 = null;
        bool labelFound = message.ApplicationProperties.TryGetValue("Label1", out var labelObj1);

        if (labelFound && labelObj1 is string labelValue)
        {
            label1 = labelValue;
        }

        var isValidOrder = Enum.TryParse<CheckOrder>(label1, out var checkOrder);

        //Rest of code logic

        return (group,CheckOrder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I received the same error code as yours like below:-

[image]

***In order to resolve this error, I have used the below code in my Function.cs and the json payload was deserialized successfully like below:-***

**Function.cs:-**

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp28
{
    public class ServiceBusMessage
    {
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string messageBody)
        {
            try
            {
                var serviceBusMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceBusMessage>(messageBody);

                _logger.LogInformation("Deserialized Message: {messageBody}", messageBody);
                _logger.LogInformation("Product ID: {productId}", serviceBusMessage.ProductId);
                _logger.LogInformation("Quantity: {quantity}", serviceBusMessage.Quantity);
                _logger.LogInformation("Order ID: {orderId}", serviceBusMessage.OrderId);
                _logger.LogInformation("Product Name: {productName}", serviceBusMessage.ProductName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while processing the message.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Json payload:-**

```json
{
    "ProductId": "ABC123",
    "Quantity": 5,
    "OrderId": 1001,
    "ProductName": "Sample Product"
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**My local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://valleysb54.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxx",
    "TopicName": "sid",
    "SubscriptionName": "desai"
  }
}
```

*Azure service-bus trigger will by default serialize the json payload and stream it refer below:-*

**Function.cs code .net 7:-**

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp28
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]